# setting currentTime in html5 video tag

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

simply setting video.currentTime = 10 wouldn't work in chrome but works superb 
  in fire fox so what should be done??
  I just created an example of having a button to set the time

```
    <template>
        <div>
    <video id="xx" controls height="300px" width="300px">
        <source src="videos/property.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="" >
    </video>                                                                     
         <button @click="changeIt">chnage</button>
         <button @click="playIt">play</button>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
     export default{
       mounted(){
          let y = document.getElementById("xx");
         y.controls=false;
               },
    methods:{
         changeIt(){
           let y = document.getElementById("xx");
           y.currentTime=15;
           console.log(video.currentTime);
                  },
         playIt(){
            let y = document.getElementById("xx");
            y.play();
            } 
         },

         }
        </script>
```

Comment: When do you call this function? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: `video.currentTime = 10` works fine in Chrome, assuming that `video` correlates to a video ID. Can you please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I created an example and firefox just sets the currentTime I can't continue without knowing the reason

Comment: At what point in the OP code does the player actually get extracted from `<template>` then `appendChild()` to the DOM?